# why the order of static Constructor is coming like this C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, static-variables, static-constructor

i have 3 class
A-->B-->C

all classes have static constructor and normal constructor

 now according to me o/p should be like

> static C 
>  Static B
>  static A
>
> A constructor
>  B constructor
>  C constructor

but it's coming like this

> static C 
>  Static A
>  static B 
>  A constructor
>  B
>   constructor
>  C constructor

can any one pls explain why it's happening 
 my code

```
class A
{
    protected static int a,b;
    protected int c;
    static A()
    {
        // a = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("static A");

    }

    public A()
    {
        // a = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("A Constructor");
        // c = 0;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    static B()
    {
        b = 20;
        // a = 30;
        Console.WriteLine("Staic B");
        // b = 20;
        // a = 30;
    }
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B Constructor");
        // c = 4;
        // a = 7;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    static C()
    {
        // a = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Static C");
    }

    public C()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C Constructor");
        // c = 0;
        // a = 70;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    C c = new C();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be in that order? Your instance constructors and your inheritance has nothing to do with your static constructors.

Comment: In `B`'s static constructor you reference `A.b`, causing `A`'s  static constructor to run first. Please read [ask] and show your research.